# @PathVariable in spring 3 how to check required value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have created one method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings/userSettings/{key}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Secured("ROLE_HOME_TAB")
public ModelAndView updateUserSetting(HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathVariable("key") String key,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String value) {
    Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

        try {
            User user = RequestUtils.getUser(request);
            UserSettings userSettings = userManager.getUserSettings(user,
                    key);
            if (userSettings == null) {
                userSettings = new UserSettings(user, key);
            }
            userSettings.setValue(value);
            userManager.saveObject(userSettings);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
        }

    return new ModelAndView(new JSONView(
            model));
}
```

But while I am starting server I am getting this error

```
Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given

Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class
```

In my `UserSetting` pojo class I am checking not null for key. How to resolve this?

I have to use `@PathVariable` only, I can't use `@RequestParam` so please help me

Answer (score 0):

PLease try :
The class you are going to proxy using CGLib has to provide a default constructor.

**Source :** http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?50210-Superclass-has-no-null-constructors-but-no-arguments-were-given